# How to design a program that finds the sum of the integers from 1 to N, where N is a value read on the keyboard?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, mips, mips32

This is my first attempt at MIPS and I designed a pseudocode description of a possible algorithm. The code outline is as follows:

```
main: Print: "Please input a value for N ="
read v0
If(v0 >0)
{
  t0 = 0
  while(v0 > 0) do
  {
    t0 = t0 + v0
    v0 = v0 +v0 -1
  }
 print: The sum of integers from 1 to N is = ", t0
 go to main
}
else
  print: "Honest Abe"
```

so, with this outline, I made somewhat of an attempt to translate this into MIPS but the whole storing variables and reading them in is confusing me. My attempt of the real code is:

```
.data
  Prompt:   .asciiz  "\n Please input a value for N="
  Result:   .asciiz  "\n The sum of integers from 1 to N is "
  Bye:      .asciiz  "\n ***Honest Abe***"

.text
  main:
        li $v0,4                #load $v0 with print_string code
        la $a0, Prompt          #load $a0 with the message to be displayed
        syscall

        bgz $v0, else
        li $t0, 0
        while:
              bgz $v0
              add $t0,$t0,$v0
              addi $v0,$vo -1
```

From here, I do not understand how the for loops work in MIPS and I do not understand if this is even the correct approach. The whole idea of reading in numbers and then storing the integers isn't processing in my head. Also, I am unsure if I am using the appropriate commands for the loop. Help to any of these questions would be great!

Comment: One way to create a loop to MIPS is making a jump to a label without a condition (j while). The other one is to loop with a condition using `slt` and `beq` commands, or simply `bgt` for the `while(v0 > 0)`.

Comment: Well, first of all, you don't need a loop since the equation for an arithmetic series is (n/2) * (n min + n max)  so in your case (counting from 1) it's (n/2)*(1+n)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems a bit odd and too much of a hassle, if I got right what you wanted to do.

You can compute a sum until a certain number with a simple for loop. As in C:

```
 scanf("%d", &num);
 for(i=0;i<num;i++)
 sum=sum+i;
```

like an array.
With a little help from the reference card of MARS, you can end up with something like this:

```
.text
main:

li  $v0, 5   #read a number from the keyboard
syscall

addi    $s0, $v0, 1    #s0= the number from the keyboard + 1 (the limit)

li  $t0, 1        #counter set to 1

loop:
    beq $t0, $s0, exit      #if the counter becomes equal tothe limit, exit the loop

    add $t1, $t1, $t0       #add the counter to the sum to this point

    addiu   $t0, $t0, 1     #add 1 to the counter for each loop

j loop                      #go to the "loop" label above

exit:

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $t1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall
```